# Undefined variable $user->username (Laravel 5.7)

Tags: php, laravel

I can't get the data from the database. Getting an error:

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
>
> Undefined variable: user
>
> (View:/Users/alex/Desktop/sites/tj/resources/views/user/submissions.blade.php)

**Controller**:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['getById', 
        'getByUsername', 'submissions', 'comments', 'showSubmissions', 
        'showComments']]);
}
```

and

```
public function showSubmissions($username)
{
    $user = new UserResource(
        User::withTrashed()->where('username', $username)->firstOrFail(),
        true
    );

    $submissions = SubmissionResource::collection(
        Submission::whereUserId($user->id)
        ->withTrashed()
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->simplePaginate(15)
    );

    return view('user.submissions', compact('user', 'submissions'));
}
```

**View**:

```
{{ $user->username }}
```

**API**:

```
Route::get('/user', 'UserController@getByUsername');
```

I need get information about user (`username`).

What is the problem and where is the error?

Comment: Can you post your routes file as well as the url you are currently on?

Comment: (web.php) Route::get('/submission', function () { return view('user.submissions'); });
I now in url mysite.com/submission

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment you have this route:

```php
Route::get('/submission', function () {
    return view('user.submissions');
});
```

When you are loading this view, you are not passing the user object to it. Then when the view is running, it is trying to access a variable that does not exist.

To fix this, you need to pass a variable to the view you are loading. For example, you could do something like this:

```php
Route::get('/submission', function () {
    return view('user.submissions', ['user' => auth()->user()]);
});
```

Note that you can change how you get the user instance depending on your use case. I am just getting the authenticated user to demonstrate the principle.

Comment: I get error now "ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Trying to get property of non-object "

Comment: That is because the user is not authenticated? In which case the user variable will be `null` and so when you try to access the `username` property within your view it is throwing that error. So if you are trying to pass in the authenticated user then you need to make sure the correct middleware is applied so that it only runs if the user is authenticated.

Comment: @Oleg that second problem is because you are returning to your view the compacted version of the variables.. this is an associative `array`. So this (`$user->username`) won't work, try this: `$user['username']` instead.